# Can't clone Mercurial repository: abort: http error 404: Not Found

Tags: iis, mercurial, repository, clone

I'm serving a [Mercurial repository using IIS7](http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/02/24/running-a-mercurial-server-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008-r2). My repository is in `C:\hg_repositories\MyRepo`.

I can browse the list of my repositories on `http://zoo/hg` and one particular repo on `http://zoo/hg/hg_repositories/MyRepo/`

My hgweb.config:

```
[collections]
/ = /hg_repositories

[web]
allow_push = *
baseurl = /hg
push_ssl = false
```

when I try to clone it with this command

```
$ hg clone http://zoo/hg/hg_repositories/MyRepo
```

I get `abort: http error 404: Not Found` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried not putting in the part of the url that the collections is referencing?  like `hg clone http://zoo/hg/MyRepo`

Comment: My hgweb.config has the full path on both sides of the = sign 

`[collections]
e:/repos = e:/repos`
I clone strait from the url on the hgweb page when i clone

Comment: @TylerSmith , I tried as you do, have the same error. What do you mean by 'I clone strait from the url on the hgweb page when i clone'? Do you mean you copy the url from browser and use it in `hg clone...` ? If so, I'm doing the same

Comment: yes i meant copying the url strait from the browser page. Its possible that your baseurl is messing it up.  I have mine unset but the tutorial on the site says to set it to /              [link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Change_the_URL_using_baseurl_and_URL_rewriting)